# Get the finished project using JavaScript in Project Server

Tags: jsom, project-server

In `Project Server`, I have a project information like **project name** , **start date, end date**.

I would like to get the finished projects list using JavaScript.

Anyone can point me out to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API of Project Server. Any project has an attribute called "FinishDate", so you only need to set the filter like this one:

```
https://<SP URL>/<PWA Site/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=FinishDate le datetime'2019-11-07T17:23:00.000Z'&$select=FinishDate,Name,StartDate
```